# How to decrypt TLS communication in wireshark when using C# webrequests

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I am trying to decrypt TLS communication between server and client in Wireshark.
I found some articles about how to do this by using the SSLKEYLOGFILE windows environment variable.
When I am using a browser such as Firefox or Chrome I can see that the SSLKEYLOGFILE gets filled.
But when I am using my own client implemented in C# using WebRequests nothing gets added to the keylogfile.

Is it possible to instruct the .net WebRequest to provide the pre-shared secret as the browsers do?
Or is there a workaround to get the secret to decrypt the traffic in Wireshark?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That'sa a *Firefox* and *Chrome* feature. You can't get this to work with any other application. If you could, every hacker would use it to steal data. If you want to decrypt data during debugging use a debugging proxy like Fiddler and set it to decrypt SSL traffic.

Comment: Ok, but since I am having the source code of both server and client I though maybe it's possible to programatically expose the shared secret so that I can use it in wireshark to decrypt.

Comment: If you want to inspect the HTTP calls, the source code in question is .NET's. You don't need Wireshark for this either, Fiddler already does the job of decrypting *and* decoding the HTTP calls

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a way with Wireshark (without adding a unencrypted proxy in between).
You can however retrieve the unencrypted payload (& more) by adding the following to your config file:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true"  />
<sources>
  <source name="System.Net" maxdatasize="10000000"  tracemode="protocolonly" >
    <listeners>
      <add name="TraceFile"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <add name="TraceFile" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="tracefile.log"/>
</sharedListeners>
<switches>
  <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
</switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent for .NET Core code using `HttpClient`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I thought there were possibilities with eventlisteners (see e.g. https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/12/23/tracing-net-core-applications#eventlistener), I just doubt there is access to the payload itself